# SFML window not clearing at random

Tags: c++, sfml

```
//in ploting.cpp
Ploting::Ploting(int winW, int winH){
    this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(winW,winH), "supercool window name");
    window->clear(sf::Color(200,200,200));
    std::cout << "window set white " << std::endl;
    window->display();
}
***
//main
#include "../include/Ploting.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int wW = 1000;
    int wH = 700;
    Ploting ploting = Ploting(wW,wH);
    ploting.display();
    while(true);
}
***
```

It may not be a very clean code, I'm sorry for that and open to suggestions but that's not my question.

Thing is when I instantiate my window i fill it white. It works wonderfully but i have figured that if i try to display my graph with the code as above, 10% of the time at random my window is black. It do display the graph and work properly but the background is just black instead of white.

I looked online and couldn't find someone with the same issue. I tried bu i can't seems to find out why this do so. Any help would be welcome.

edit : Apparently it now even happenned without calling the draw draph. Even just after the instantiation the window seems to sometimes not be white at all.

edit : So the issue seems to have been caused by the useless display in the instantiation.

Comment: So clear the window as part of `drawGraph`?

Comment: Also, how does your `main` function handle events coming from SFML? Are you handling events properly and redrawing periodically? Show some more of your `main`.

Comment: clearing inside the drawGraph isn't fixing it. nice try i guess but it was still strange and i'm curious to understand why it does that. Also i do handle event in the main with a listening fuction but for the purpose of finding the bug i even disabled anything that i didn't posted.

Comment: We cannot help you further without a [mre], which includes the bits of your main function that drive the drawing...

Comment: This is the minimal reproductible example... As i said to find the source of the bug i fully commented my main, i don't even call the event handler, i don't update the window, i do nothing outside of what above. And as i edited this, the error seems to reproduce even without having to call drawGraph. The error may be a missunderstanding of the clear function or a weird memory unfafe thing i do ? I'm sorry but at this point i can't make it more "minimal and reproductible" as the only 30ish line i run are posted. (outside of the graph generation that i don't believe is in fault)

Comment: I am mostly interested in how your `main` function calls the draw function. Does it call it once? In a loop? Does it respond to events? ..

Comment: Alright so i just realized i displayed my window in the instantiation and that it made no sense. After i removed the line, the issue stopped. I guess the fact i tried to display 2 times the same window, that i shouldn't do that and that it was what caused the bug.